# Session not taking text from form

Tags: php, forms, session

I have not found an answer anywhere else.
Still having a problem adding form textbox values to the session. The code as it stands won't even add to the session from this particular form. It had before until I closed the browser to restart the session. When it was sending the session correctly to the second page the values for fname, lname, address ect was fname:|N which I am assuming in a null value? Every page the sesson_start(); is called at the top.
Code for the form:

```
 <form method='post' action='email.php'>
First name:  <input type="text" name="fname"/><br />
Last name:   <input type="text" name="lname"/><br />
Address:     <input type="text" name="address"/><br />
City:        <input type="text" name="city"/><br />
State:       <input type="text" name="state" /><br />
Zip code:    <input type="text" name="zip"/><br />
Email:       <input type="text" name="email"/><br />
<button type="submit" name="submit">Continue to checkout</button>
</form> 
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname']; 
//$_SESSION['fname'] = $var_fname;
$_SESSION['lname'] = $_POST['lname'];
$_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
$_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
$_SESSION['state'] = $_POST['state'];
$_SESSION['zip'] = $_POST['zip'];
$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
}
?>
```

Code on second page echo'ing the session:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo $var_session = json_encode($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <?php
    echo session_encode();
    //echo $var_email = json_encode($_SESSION["email"]);
    //echo $var_fname = json_encode($_SESSION["fname"]);
    //echo $var_email = $_SESSION["email"];
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't see a `session_start()` in your first PHP snippet, and I don't see anywhere that `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']` is set either.

Comment: Also, `isset($_POST['submit'])` will never be true, because there are no form elements with that name, so your session setting code will never be called. You can add `name="submit"` to your submit button to fix that.

Comment: Also also, there is no benefit to setting all of your $_POST variables to local variables before assigning to the session, except for making the code look messy. (Unless you are using those variables later on in the same script). You can just set the session directly `$_SESSION['zip'] = $_POST['zip'];`

Comment: The' session_start()' is at the top of the page. And '$_SESSION['shoping_cart']' is set up on the page as well. I made all of the changes suggested and they are still not being sent to the second page. The shopping cart session array is though. Does the script need to be inside the form tag?

Comment: Update the code in your question. The script processing the form data and the form itself are completely separate, so no.

Comment: Updated the code in the question.